# SonarQube 'unable to locate any of the following binaries'

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am in the process of trying to install a later version of sonarqube on linux redhat. Have transferred over config and properties file details, then when i go to execute sonar.sh start I get an error saying:

> "Unable to locate any of the following binaries: /opt/sonar.....
>   /opt/sonarq/sonarqube-5.6.6/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper (found but not
>   executable)."

I was wondering if anyone has bumped into this and knows why the sonar.sh is not executable

many thanks in advance

Comment: You "copied over config and properties file". (You're not actually supposed to do that.) Are you sure they point to the right locations?

Comment: Hi sorry, that was the wrong speech, I mean i copied over the details - not the files and overwriting.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, for me it was execute permission. Just set execute permission on the wrapper in sonarqube-X.X/bin/[version]/wrapper.

**$ chmod 764 wrapper**

That should do the trick, if not, make sure you're the owner of the sonarqube-X.X folder